# Cancel the definition of a command or environment

Tags: packages, environments, renewcommand

I will have to use for a few weeks two packages having common commands/environments (with the same name).

I would like to be able to :

- import the first package,
- "delete" the definition of certain commands or environments (those in the second package),
- import the second package.

Is this possible?

Comment: yes if they both define a `zzz` environment use `\let\zzz\undefined \let\endzzz\undefined` after the first package

Comment: Thanks. Is it the same for commands ?

Comment: Commands don't need to worry about the `\end` part.  What are the packages?  The usual TeX packages shouldn't conflict, and if a custom package is conflicting, you might be able to talk with the package author.

Comment: These are the `pythontex` and `pyluatex` packages. I would like to progressively use only the last one but there is still a feature of `pythontex` not present in `pyluatex`. The commands `\py` and `\pyc` are used by each package.

Comment: Surprisingly `\let\py\undefined`does'nt fix the issue for `\py`,but it does for `\pyc`